# Python Counter() adding value to existing keys

Tags: python, dictionary

```
developer_base = Counter({
        'user1': {'XS': 0, 'S': 0, 'M': 0, 'L': 0, 'XL': 0},
        'user2': {'XS': 0, 'S': 0, 'M': 0, 'L': 0, 'XL': 0},
        'user3': {'XS': 0, 'S': 0, 'M': 0, 'L': 0, 'XL': 0},
        'user4': {'XS': 0, 'S': 0, 'M': 0, 'L': 0, 'XL': 0},
    })
```

Loop to gather Counter data:

```
for y in time_list:
                story_size = models.get_specific_story(y['story_id'])
                if story_size is not "?":
                    counts = Counter(y['minutes_spent'])
                    print(counts)
                    developer_base = developer_base + counts
```

Should `Counter`be part of a for loop? story_size always equals one of the keys in the nested dict (S,XS,M etc). `time_list` has the ['minutes_spent'] which is the value that needs to add into the dictionary. the problem seems to be that time_list has a nested dict which is ['user']['first_name'] and it is equal to the developer_base keys for user1 through user4.

So I need to add up all the 'minutes_spent' in time_list for each user.

Update: JSON data

```
[{'project_slug': 'test', 'project_id': 19855, 'date': '2016-02-11', 'task_name': None, 'iteration_name': 'test', 'notes': '', 'user_id': 81946, 'story_id': 392435, 'iteration_id': 76693, 'story_name': 'test', 'user': {'id': 81946, 'last_name': 'test', 'first_name': 'user1', 'email': 'test', 'username': 'test'}, 'project_name': 'Development', 'id': 38231, 'minutes_spent': 240}]
```

The data is much larger but this is one whole section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first snippet, you are abusing `Counter`. That snippet only works due to quirks in Python 2, where one can compare dicts. The values of a counter are supposed to be numbers.

Similarly, `y['minutes_spent']` is an integer, and `Counter(y['minutes_spent'])` will just throw an error. In addition, `story_size is not "?"` [does not do what you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/132988/35070).

Assuming the real problem is

> add up all the 'minutes_spent' in time_list for each user.

then you can use a Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
for y in time_list:
    c[y['user']['id']] += y['minutes_spent']
```

Comment: I'm having such a hard time understanding how Counter() actually works. your suggested did help! so I'm moving in the right direction. Thank you very much for clarifying the "quirk" for P2 that I was trying to use in P3.5. I did change the "is not" to "!=" instead as I only "assumed" the is not part would work.

Comment: `Counter` is basically a `defaultdict(int)` with a couple of helper methods.

Comment: Going through the docs on Counter now. I still think I'm not handling this correctly has in your example above for c[y['user']['id']] , when I add the next nested key of ['story_size'] it throws the TypeError: string indices must be integers. 

Are nested key:value assignments now allowed through Counter?

Comment: @SudoGaron My magic crystall ball says that `y` is not what you think in that case, and completely unrelated to `Counter`.

Comment: ah yeah there is no key of story_size it's the actual variable created. c[y['user']['first_name'][story_size] won't work either since it's from a separate object not in `y`. I'll look into building keys from separate objects and see how it goes.